# is it necessary to have instance variables in a UITableViewCell subclass?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Question - Is it necessary to have subview (e.g. UILabel) instance variables in a UITableViewCell subclass?

The alternative I am thinking of being to construct say the UILabels you want for your custom UITableViewCell subclass when you create it, assign them to the content view (e.g. [self.contentView addSubview:label_1]), and then release the UILabel (e.g. [label_1 release]).

So is it the case the only reason you need to keep the labels as instance variables (declared in the header) of the UITableViewCell subclass, so that you can grab them more easily to configure/make changes to them later.  That is as opposed to having to find through by looking them up directly in the contentView via their tag values?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a convenience, but one worth sticking with. if you call viewWithTag everytime something needs to be changed/redrawn it can be less efficient than just using the pointer stored in the stack, as this would have to be recalculated each time.

Comment: thanks McCannon - so I guess you're pointing out to me that even if I had a lot of UILabels, they would only be pointers to the same contentView lables so I shouldn't worry about the size of the class so-to-speaak.

Comment: how many labels are you going to have in your tableViewCell? Generally you don't want more than two per cell.

Comment: well it could be up to say 5-10 rows of 3 columns, so that would be 30 UILabels.  Is there a performance issue here?  Perhaps I should be just putting the text all in one UILabel and using a non-proportional font & string formatting to make it appear like it's all aligned in a table like fashion?

Comment: see how it goes, if the view scrolls well when you test it with data then don't worry, if it is jumpy then that could be something to look at.